# Analyzing Google Trends data

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I am using Google Trends data for work, and have to determine if certain terms were searched significantly more frequently during a certain period. Right now, I'm doing no preprocessing on the data, and just using the t-test to test if the points in each time period come from the same distribution.

Are there any ways to do this more effectively? In particular, should I preprocess the data in any way? Are there any specific techniques for time series? Any help is appreciated!

P.S. Here is what Google Trends data look like. In Google's words: "A value of 100 is the peak popularity for the term. A value of 50 means that the term is half as popular. A score of 0 means there was not enough data for this term."

[image: Google Trends Data]

Comment: "if certain terms were searched significantly more frequently during a certain period", since Google scales the data it looks like you can't tell which term would be searched MORE but which term relative to itself is being searched more.  Is that what you want or are there other data slices which contain actual values? Or are you looking more to create like seasonal profiles for the search terms?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare different periods for the same term, so i don't think the data scaling is relevant.

Comment: Then yeah I would do some sort of seasonal decomposition to get the seasonalities.  One easy and effective way would be to use fbProphet: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/ .  Then just compare the seasonality in the output across search terms.